# Saving canvas drawing to sd card

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I m currently working on canvas drawing in which i hv a canvas with white colored background ( with **canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);**) and a sketched image of cartoons comics that allows to paint with some colors. The problem is that when i go to save the canvas image only a black screen with color done get saved neither the canvas white background nor the sketched image is appeared..
I m using this code for saving canvas

```
public void saveAsJpg (File f)
    {
        String fname = f.getAbsolutePath ();
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try 
        {
            fos = new FileOutputStream (f);
            mBitmap.compress (CompressFormat.JPEG, 95, fos);
            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "Saved " + fname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) 
        {
            Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext(), "Error: " + ex.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
            ex.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }
```

Please help,,,,
Thnx in advance

Comment: What does 'canvas' mean in this context? Is this Java? Android?

Comment: Sooo sorry for not mentioning it before, it is **Android canvas**

Comment: You neither flush nor close your output stream. Of doing that doesn't help, you'll have to show the code that attaches the Bitmap to the Canvas. See also: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/11/drawing-with-canvas-in-android-saving.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my drawing get saved. The changes i need to made in code is to create a bitmap along-with the canvas by command **mCanvas = new Canvas( mBitmap );**, which turn my canvas background as the image background..
Previously i had only started to painting the canvas which has black color background by default.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?
Write in your manifest file this permittion. . .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```